# Force blocking syscall of other thread to return and set errno to EINTR

Tags: c++, linux

please view the following example source code:

```
void tfunc()
{
    // Some blocking syscall that sets errno
    if (errno == EINTR)
   {
        std::cout << "cleanup" << std::endl;
       return;
   }
   // Do some other stuff
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::thread t(tfunc);
    sleep(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible, from another thread, to have the syscall, for example `accept()` return and set `errno` to `EINTR`? If yes, how?

Comment: Depends a lot on the actually used blocking function, the C library etc. If you can then rather design for non blocking system calls

Comment: @DanielJour Thy for your answer. It is mostly socket operation like accept() or read() on that socket. All used functions will support EINTR. Is there no way to bypass the nonblocking polling on a bool as exit condition or something like that?

Comment: no, don't poll; there's select for that

Comment: @DanielJour Thy. I dont quite see the direction you are trying to push me to. Select would block too, wouldnt it? Unless I would set its timeout to 0. What would I have gained here since the thread would still be blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use:

- non-blocking operations
- `poll()` (or `select()` or `epoll()`)
- a pipe

Before you spawn your thread you setup a pipe which will carry an "interrupt message".  In your thread `tfunc` you setup `poll` such that it waits on both the file descriptor (socket) you want to work on *and* the read end of the pipe.

If you want to interrupt that you simply write an "interrupt message" to the write end of the pipe; and in the thread check on return of `poll` whether the pipe has data to read.

Small demo, no error handling, no handling of signals, just to visualize what I mean:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>


#include <poll.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int fd[2];

void the_blocking_thread(void)
{
    pollfd pollfds[2];
    pollfds[0].fd = fd[0];
    pollfds[0].events = POLLIN;
    pollfds[1].fd = -99; // add here your socket / fd
    pollfds[1].events = POLLIN; // or whatever you need
    std::cout << "waiting for \"interrupt message\" or real work on fd" << std::endl;
    int ret = poll(pollfds, 2, -1);
    assert(ret > 0);
    if (pollfds[0].revents != 0) {
        std::cout << "cleanup" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    // Non blocking call on your fd
    // Some other stuff
}


int main() {
    int ret = pipe(fd);
    assert(ret == 0);
    std::cout << "Starting thread" << std::endl;
    std::thread t(the_blocking_thread);
    std::chrono::seconds timespan(1); // or whatever
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(timespan);
    std::cout << "Sending \"interrupt\" message" << std::endl;
    char dummy = 42;
    ret = write (fd[1], &dummy, 1);
    assert(ret == 1);
    t.join();
}
```

([Live](https://ideone.com/U1hwhP))

Comment: Thank you, this works great. Marking this as the working solution. For my simple case I found a call of the linux library function "shutdown" to be releasing blocking socket operations too.